# Django Blog Text Formatting (Beginner)

Tags: python, html, django, blogs, text-formatting

was just wondering how I would go about formatting text while entering it into my admin page from django in a blog app. I have the very basic code for the article/blog app.

In models.py:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    body = models.TextField()
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    likes = models.IntegerField()
def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

Is there something that I need to add in the "body" variable? I tried just typing something like

```
<br>
```

in the text while typing in the text field while in the django admin page for posting articles. The html file looks like this btw:

```
<h1>{{ article.title }}</h1>
<p>{{ article.body }}</p>
```

But no change in the text I entered. Would anybody be able to help? I've been searching and maybe I'm not doing the best job of looking, but I can't seem to find how to do this. Just want it to be simple to edit the text while writing a blog post.

Thank you in advance for any help and/or advice, it is appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please try the [linebreaks](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#linebreaks) built-in filter. Use it like this:

```
...
<p>{{ article.body|linebreaks }}</p>
```

Now in your admin page you could insert new lines as you'd do in any text editor you use.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want a WYSIWYG editor, there are a multitude. I've used TINYMCE in Django before with no problems, [here](http://www.tinymce.com/).

Comment: Thank you for the link, I'm looking this all up, now. Although it may not solve my question immediately, this may lead to better things down the road. Thank you!